# Declaring "native" types in Perl 6

Tags: raku, nativecall

In the [`natives.pm6` module](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/98e575de00db42101d4879e43fe740a34791c418/src/core/natives.pm6), many native types are declared this way:

```perl6
my native int is repr('P6int') is Int { }
```

You can apparently use it in the same way,

```perl6
my native smallish is repr('P6int') is Int is nativesize(8) { };
say smallish.^mro; # OUTPUT: «((smallish) (Int) (Cool) (Any) (Mu))␤»
```

Apparently, you need `native` to specify a representation, since that will fail if `native`is not used. Same with [`is repr`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#index-entry-is_repr), so they go hand in hand. However, this is just a behavioral observation.

However, I haven't found any documentation of when and where to use `native`, other than those examples in the implementation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked lib/experimental.pm6 ?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I actually did, there are a bunch of other definitions using it there. But all I can do, as said above, is deduct behavior from observation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `native` package declarator is a Rakudo Perl 6 compiler implementation detail rather than part of the Perl 6 language. Some mechanism was needed to express the relationship between the language runtime and types like `int32` and `num64` declared in the Perl 6 standard library. A different type of meta-object was needed for natives, and since package declarators (like `class` and `role`) work by being mapped to a particular type of meta-object, introducing a `native` package declarator for this purpose was a neat way to bootstrap that bit of the Perl 6 type system.

Use of `native` outside of the standard library was never intended (which I can say with confidence, because I invented the mechanism). Given the performance sensitivity of native types, Perl 6 compiler developers should likely be given maximum freedom to choose how they define them, and to be able to refine that over time. There's no certainty that the `native` declarator will exist forevermore in Rakudo, nor that any future Perl 6 compiler developers will choose to do things in the same way.

If wanting an alias to a native type name, just use `constant`:

```
constant smallish = int;
```

Since `constant` is evaluated at compile time, this symbol can then be used just like any other type. There's no functionality otherwise available through `native` that isn't already exposed by types available in Perl 6 or the `NativeCall` library.